# GA 360 export to Big Query - delete or update ga_sessions data?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

Is it possible to either delete or update data from datasets that have been imported from GA ( [BQ export schema](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en) )?

Ideally, I would like to delete or update only individual records using DML.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/updating-data

If that is not possible, I would like to know if I could delete/overwrite an entire daily table that looks like **{gaviewid}.ga_sessions_YYYYMMDD**
 ?

Comment: Sure, why not? Have you tried running UPDATE/DELETE statements over those tables? The one thing you can't do is run such a statement over multiple tables (days) at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for clarifing Elliot. I just haven’t come across a use case where I would needed to delete that data until now. I wanted to confirm that this type of dataset didn’t have special permissions to avoid someone from accidentally deleting it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can using standard SQL. Google may update these tables at a later point in time through once they re-calculate traffic source (Ads) therefore overwriting your changes.

Comment: is there any reference doc you can point me to. I need to show this to my business for a problem statement i am working on.
Thanks,
Jai